# How to set foreign keys that has a composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a school database system and had an error in one table called **ExamDesc** because it has a composite primary key but when I set the foreign key it couldn't run. So I have this table called ExamDesc:

```
CREATE TABLE `ExamDesc` (
  `ExamID` INT NOT NULL,
  `StudentID` INT NOT NULL,
  `NumberOfStudents` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ExamID`, `StudentID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`ExamID`) REFERENCES `Exam`(`ExamID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID`) REFERENCES `Student`(`StudentID`)
);
```

A table called Student:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `StudentID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `StudentName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `ClassID` INT NOT NULL,
  `G-SuiteID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `ReportID` INT NOT NULL,
  `AttendanceID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`ClassID`) REFERENCES `Class`(`ClassID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`G-SuiteID`) REFERENCES `G-SuiteID Account`(`G-SuiteID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`ReportID`) REFERENCES `Report Card`(`ReportID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`AttendanceID`) REFERENCES `Attendance`(`AttendanceID`)
);
```

And a table called Exam:

```
CREATE TABLE `Exam` (
  `ExamID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `SubjectCode` INT NOT NULL,
  `ExamTime` TIME NOT NULL,
  `ExamRoom` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `ExamDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ExamID`)
);
```

Basically the composite primary key consists of two keys, one I put as a foreign key in the **Student** table and another one I put as a foreign key in the **Exam** table. Is this a correct way to do it?

Comment: Your code is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d6cec5adf9a267412669ef22780a44d.  I suspect that you just need to define the tables before you can create a foreign key reference to them.

Comment: The tables should work well. What error do you get?

Comment: I got this error: (errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”), but now it's solved basically cause what Gordon said which is the declaring tables order. I should declare Exam and Student table first but instead I did the opposite so that's why.